# Android - Can export one App in Several Version

Tags: android

Can I export one program to several android app version.
ex. I code calculator app that can detect device smartphone, tablet, galaxy note. export 2 app > calculator, calculator for tablet, calculator for galaxy note.

Answer (score 2):

[Android Developers - Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I can code program for multi-screen size, but I want to export different screen size to multi app like smarthpone version and tablet version. Can you have any idea.

Comment: It's highly recommended that you ship a single app that will work on all devices rather than multiple apps.